# if divergence of a vector is zero, how to find the spherical coordinate of the vector?

Tags: vectors, electromagnetism

The perturbed part of magnetic field is $\mathbf{\delta B}$ where $\mathbf{\delta B} = \delta B_x(x,y), \delta B_y(x,y)$ and
$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\delta B} = 0$.

To prove $\mathbf{\delta B} = \delta B(-sin\phi, cos\phi)$ in spherical coordinates?

I was trying :
$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\delta B} = 0$,

$\mathbf{\delta B}$ in terms of spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$.

in Cartesian coordinates:
$ \mathbf{\delta B} = \delta B_x \mathbf{\hat{i}} + \delta B_y \mathbf{\hat{j}} $

In spherical coordinates, the Cartesian unit vectors are:

$ \mathbf{\hat{i}} = \sin\phi\cos\theta \mathbf{\hat{r}} + \cos\phi\cos\theta \mathbf{\hat{\theta}} - \sin\theta \mathbf{\hat{\phi}} $

$ \mathbf{\hat{j}} = \sin\phi\sin\theta \mathbf{\hat{r}} + \cos\phi\sin\theta \mathbf{\hat{\theta}} + \cos\theta \mathbf{\hat{\phi}} $

but the actual expression $\mathbf{\delta B} = \delta B(-sin\phi, cos\phi)$ is not coming.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The divergence of $\vec B$ is zero.  What are you asking?